# $ e $$ agora são funções nativas dos navegadores?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, dom

Ao usar o console em uma página sem JavaScript notei que ao digitar `$` tinha o mesmo efeito que `document.querySelector` e ao digitar `$$` tinha o mesmo efeito que o `document.querySelectorAll`.

Seriam duas funções atalhos para o querySelector ou elas tem algum comportamento especifico diferente?

Qual o nome delas? Eu até procurei no caniuse http://caniuse.com/#search=%24%24, mas não obtive resultado (tentei "dollar" também)

Comment: São métodos que vêm com o console.

Comment: @bfavaretto teria um nome? Pesquisei por "dollar sign"

Comment: @bfavaretto na verdade só fiz a pergunta mesmo pra existir no site :p .. mas se tiver uma dup pra indicar ficarei grato

Comment: Também acho bom ter a pergunta no site. Só não tenho tempo de pesquisar pra colocar uma resposta decente agora, por isso o primeiro comentário.

Answer (score 9):

Isso são métodos somente da consola, atalhos para facilitar o programador.

Isso confirma-se na [documentação do Chrome aqui](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference) e na [documentação do Edge aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/f12-devtools-guide/console#selecting-elements-in-the-console) onde diz:

> **$()** é um atalho para document.querySelector().
>   **$$()** é um atalho para document.querySelectorAll().
>   **$0**, **$1**, **$2**, **$3**, **$4** devolve os ultimos elementos selecionados pelo explorador do DOM (elements)

Existe ainda o **`$_`** mas esse tem um comportamento diferente no Chrome e Edge:

Edge:

> **$_()** é um atalho para ultimo objeto/elemento.

Chrome:

> **$_** é um atalho para mostrar o valor da ultima expressão avaliada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]